# Timelapse - Exaggerated blinking

Tags: time-lapse

I have a Timelapse question. We recorded about 22 minutes of a woman and boy lying on the ground around sunset to show the passing of time from day to night. We would like the shot in the film to be closer to 10-30 seconds.

I think the editor may have just changed the speed settings. Anyway, the problem is that the woman's blinking and the child's breathing both look very exaggerated now.

Is there any way to fix this in After Effects or Premiere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Import the footage into After Effects. Bring it into a comp and change the speed of the layer either with the speed control for the layer or with time remapping. Make sure the layer has **Frame Blending** turned on, and that it's on for your final render. Frame blending will blend all of the frames that make up a single frame, so if 20 minutes makes 10 seconds that's… er… 120 frames of original footage to make one frame of timelapse. This should mean that any quick motion in the original footage will blur away, and it should get rid of your blinks and breathing. If that's not enough you might want to try either the **Time Warp** at 100% speed with a long shutter time or even **wide time** effects to ad extra 'temporal blurring' to the footage.

Note that you'll have to render out the clips rather than using Dynamic Linking, because Premiere won't do the frame blends like AE does. Expect very slow renders.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, depending on the shot / lighting:

Make two comps- one is your time lapse, and one is your two subjects playing in real time, not time lapsed.

Mask (and feather) around the subjects, so the surrounding is moving quickly, but they are breathing and blinking in normal time.

Slightly crazier idea:
Track the parts of your subjects that look weird, then replace only those parts with realtime playback masks- ie the eyes and the chest?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways. First one is for if you're feeling lucky; the second one will require manual sifting, and the third is a different approach.

**Method 1**

Increasing speed in editor usually means undersampling the footage i.e. showing every *n*th frame. So, try trimming the in-point of the original unspeeded footage by a few frames, say, half a second's worth and then apply the speed change. That should offset the undersampling selection by those many frames. You may get lucky and retain fewer 'blinking' frames in the final result.

**Method 2**

Increase the speed of the original footage to create a result of around 2 minutes. Let's say your final output is supposed to be 20 seconds. You now have to trim 5 out of 6 frames. So, scan the result, split the footage every 6 frames and keep 1 in each segment, deleting the rest. This will be time-consuming, but should work as last resort.

**Method 3**

This might not create a smooth timelapse but could be acceptable. Select 20 one-second segments at around equal intervals from the original unspeeded footage. Join them together and extend the clips at the joins by 4 or 5 frames (on both sides) to create a 8-10 frame dissolve. Since the segments are curated, you can avoid all blinking. The chief issue here would be subjects' motion across segments. You'll have smooth motion within a segment but could have a 'jerky' change during a dissolve. So potential for a weird visual rhythm.